# How to make less to work with basset in laravel 4?

Tags: php, less, laravel, laravel-4

How to enable Less compiling with basset? My basset config file collection:

```php
'collections' => array(

    'application' => function($collection)
    {
        $collection->apply('UriRewriteFilter');

        $directory = $collection->directory('../app/assets/stylesheets', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->add('less/design.less')->apply('Less');
        });
        $directory->apply('CssMin');
    }
);
```

Everything else in config is untouched.

In the source code i get this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Job/public/ph7mOzIaRTYLhvwL/application/6f5128120be8f13c4a2109051990f113/design.css" />`

Even thought it's .css but it's not compiled into it.

#### Less filter

```
'Less' => array('LessFilter', function($filter)
        {
            $filter->whenAssetIs('*.less')->findMissingConstructorArgs();
        }),
```

I'm using windows.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac, Linux?  Have you confirmed what's in the Less filter?  Does it depend on any external programmes?

Comment: Windows and i don't really know if it depends on something, i didn't find that on docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the node.js builder for less you can also use the php less builder:

Add the following require to your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "leafo/lessphp": "*"
}
```

```
composer update
```

Change the Less filter alias in your basset config file to:

```
'Less' => array('LessphpFilter', function($filter)
```

Comment: Very nice - had no idea about this.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and was going a little bit mad trying to work it out. I'm working on Mac OS X, but it could be the same issue - ie. it looked like it had compiled and I got the long CSS filename exactly like you did, but the LESS had not compiled.

I saw in the error log for Basset the following:

```
[2013-06-03 20:13:13] basset.ERROR: Failed to find required 
constructor argument for filter "LessFilter". 
(Parameter #0 [ <optional> $nodeBin = '/usr/bin/node' ])
```

So I realised that the LESS filter was looking for Node.js to do the actual compiling. I didn't have Node.js installed... so I installed it, and ran `php artisan basset:build application` again.

It worked.

So have you got Node.js installed? If not, I think you need to do that. Then you'll need to install the actual modules, for example `npm install less` will install LESS when run from the command line.

Once you've done that, Windows is a little bit more tricky to inform about the path to executables (ie. the LESS compiler), so you might need to enter some paths yourself. There's more info here: http://jasonlewis.me/code/basset/4.0/filters#filter-executables under the "Windows Compatibility" section.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I faced this issue just now. Node and Less were already installed, with `/usr/bin/node` symlinked to the actual location of `/usr/local/bin/node`. Still I was getting the error you were. When I changed the line `$filter->whenAssetIs('.*\.less')->findMissingConstructorArgs();` to remove the `findMissingConstructorArgs()` call I had an error saying node couldn't find the `less` module. Giving it the path to node_modules solved the issue. Final line: `$filter->whenAssetIs('.*\.less')->setArguments('/usr/local/bin/node', [base_path() . '/node_modules']);`