# Laravel 4, Basset, Less - preg_match compilation failed

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, less, laravel-4

Background: I am using Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.5.1-2, and Laravel 4.

When I run:

```
php artisan basset:build
```

I get the error

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"preg_match(): 
Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0",
"file":"\/home\/ryan\/MyApp6\/vendor\/jasonlewis\/basset\
/src\/Basset\/Filter\/Filter.php","line":241}}
```

My problem is similar to this: [How to make less to work with basset in laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751054/how-to-make-less-to-work-with-basset-in-laravel-4)

However, I have tried the LessphpFilter, and I have do node.js installed... I can manually compile a stylesheet with node, but neither will work for me through basset.

for example, given mytest.less:

```
@color:blue;
body{
    background-color: red;
    color:@color;
}
```

MyApp/app/config/packages/jasonlewis/basset/config.php

```
'collections' => array(

    'mytest-css' => function($collection)
    {

        $collection->directory('assets/bs3/css', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->add('../less/mytest.less')->apply('Less');            
        })->apply('UriRewriteFilter')->setArguments(public_path());
    },
...
```

When I pull the page up in the browser, the background is red, but the text is still black.  In Chrome devtools, I can see a compiled css file, but the content is still:

```
@color:blue;

body{
    background-color: red;
    color:@color;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Even a hint as to how to approach tracking this down would be appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LessphpFilter is what I needed, in app/config/packages/jasonlewis/basset/config.php

I also need to add a leading slash as follows:

```
'Less' => array('LessphpFilter', function($filter)
{
    $filter->whenAssetIs('/*.less')->findMissingConstructorArgs();
}),
```

I hope that helps someone else.